# Injected cdi bean doesn't hold variable

Tags: jsf-2, dependency-injection, cdi

Hi I have experimented @Inject annotation with cdi bean. I have one variable in first bean which is injected into second bean. When I call method on second bean using variable in first bean, during that method call first bean's variable returns null.

Here is xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Experiments</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="main_form">
        <h:inputText id="nameInput" value="#{myBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value ="ok" action="#{myBean2.print()}">
            <f:ajax execute="nameInput" render="nameOutput"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:outputText id ="nameOutput" value="#{myBean2.name}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

beans:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable
    @Named(value = "myBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class MyBean implements Serializable {

        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of myBean
         */
        public MyBean() {
        }
    }
```

second bean: when I call print method of mybean2, injected myBean's 'name' property returns null.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named
        @Named(value = "myBean2")
        @SessionScoped
        public class MyBean2 implements Serializable{
            String name;
            @Inject
            MyBean myBean;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }


            public String print(){
                this.name = this.myBean.name;
                return null;
            }
            /**
             * Creates a new instance of myBean2
             */
            public MyBean2() {


    }
    }
```

Is that normal or something wrong with code or config?

Comment: Can you post your import statements as well?  Also, I'm assuming this UI is a JSF2 facelet, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I added imports

Comment: How are you confirming that `myBean.name==null`? You also realize that you're narrowing the scope of the class-level `name` variable within the `print()`?

Comment: I'm confirming that by debugging. I also did some modification. Please see

Comment: @odgiivH are your modifications based on the actual working code you have or just in response to my comment?

Comment: it's based on actual code

Comment: It seems like injected myBean gets new instance.